# How to make facebook FB.login() dialog box on top.location

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am building an Facebook IFrame App ,I request user to allow permissions for the application.When user login my App for the first time,the IFrame App will popup a window to  request user to allow permissions.

My question is:I dont want this permissions window to popup, can this popup window be something like  "top.location.href" ,just on the top of my App page.

My code is

```
         window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init({appId: '', 
                    status: true, 
                    cookie: true, 
                    xfbml: true, 
                    oauth : true //enables OAuth 2.0
                    });


            FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
                if (response.authResponse) {

                } else {
                    FB.login();

                }
            });

        };
        (function() {
            var e = document.createElement('script');
            e.type = 'text/javascript';
            e.src = document.location.protocol +
                '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
            e.async = true;
            document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
        }());

        FB.login(function(response) {
           if (response.authResponse) {
             console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
             FB.api('/me', function(response) {
               console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
               FB.logout(function(response) {
                 console.log('Logged out.');
               });
             });
           } else {
             console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
           }
         }, {scope: 'email'});
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to redirect your whole page to the authorisation dialog, yes?

If so, you just need to redirect your page to this one:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_URL&scope=email
```

...where YOUR_URL is the page you want to take them to after the permissions screen.